# How to convert (broken) MPEG1 video to format that can be viewed by most people

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I found this old (possibly broken) MPEG1 video that I'd like to share. MPC-HC manages to play it, but most players cannot render it.

How can I fix and/or convert it to a format that most people can easily view?

I tried ffmpeg, but it fails with decoding errors. I also tried uploading to YouTube, a few GIF makers, and some online video conversion sites.

If you'd like to give it a try, I've shared the MPEG1 video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OA7VNA6pYNp-2zrxYm9IxI6f8-1b4dA/view?usp=sharing).

And here is the output of ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -i penguin.mpeg  penguin.mp4
ffmpeg version N-87871-g7480f232d2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 79.100 / 55. 79.100
  libavcodec     57.108.100 / 57.108.100
  libavformat    57. 84.100 / 57. 84.100
  libavdevice    57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
  libavfilter     6.108.100 /  6.108.100
  libswscale      4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libswresample   2. 10.100 /  2. 10.100
  libpostproc    54.  8.100 / 54.  8.100
[mpeg1video @ 000001f671ae3a00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 86 times
[mpegvideo @ 000001f671ac1ca0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mpegvideo @ 000001f671ac1ca0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[mpegvideo @ 000001f671ac1ca0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg1video, none(tv), 360x288, 921 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegvideo, from 'penguin.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:00:03.46, bitrate: 921 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, none(tv), 360x288, 921 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg1video @ 000001f671ae3ec0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg1video @ 000001f671ae3ec0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg1video @ 000001f671ae3ec0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
...
...
...
Nothing was written into output file 0 (penguin.mp4), because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 2):

Why waste time trying to fix it?  You can spend hours in failed attempts.

Since you can play it on your computer, you can use a screen recording program and capture the video as you play it to a usable format.

Programs such as VLC, OBS Studio, and countless others can capture video from desktop sessions.